# Rotate or overlay an PNG image while I see extra white or black spaces in opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, overlay

I would like to overlay a PNG image on another one using opencv and python.  As I illustrated here, suppose I have pic1 and I want to rotate the picture 45 degree and have the picture 2. Then overlay the result to another one. but unfortunately I got pic 4 with this extra black area.
So i tried to make a PNG file like pic 2, and overlay it , but I got pic 3! which i dont this extra white space to be seen.
I would really appreciate it  if someone could help to write the python code, to solve this problem.  Please see the picture from here :

[image: the result of overlying png file with opencv and python]

The code I was using for rotating and overlying is this :

```
background = Image.open("back.jpg")

product = Image.open("pr.png")

img = cv2.imread('aliO3.PNG',0)

rows,cols = img.shape

M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),45,1)

dst = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))

im = Image.fromarray(dst)

background.paste(im, (pt[0] ,pt[1]))

background.save("newImage.jpg")
```

Comment: Where do you get `background` from?

Comment: OpenCV is not at all user friendly. If you don't need the specialized computer vision algorithms in opencv, the [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/) image module is easier to learn.

Comment: I have edited the quesiton

Comment: but I have to detect some objects in the picture then apply this overlying . That's why I am using opencv. But I just want to overlay a PNG file

Comment: You might want to load the image in grayscale for the computer vision, but then also load it in colour with alpha for the final display. `cv2.imread('ali03.png', 0)` is single channel (grayscale). So that's probably why the background is black in your final result. `cv2.imread('ali03.png', -1)` should load the image with alpha. That adds a third dimension to the `ndarray`, though since your image will have four channels: RGBa.

Comment: could you please write me the code? thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11938647/5987 for rotating an image in PIL with a transparent background.

Comment: you are right, since I am not very good in image processing, i didnt know what was the technical meaning behind grayscale. ...  I know I could search and read about it, but the reason I posted my question here is because I waned to ask some expert guys,

Comment: Thank you mark, I really appreciate it